# Beginner Web Service Question

Tags: java, web-services

I want to send a request to a web service, and read the response.
So far, I used JAXB to generate Java classes from an XSD, which I am assuming I will use to read the response?

What is the best way for me to implement the request? The web service I am using is a servlet and requires a POST. Is my only option to send a string that is a SOAP request using HttpURLConnection?

Comment: What kind of Webservice is it? Is it a REST Service or is it SOAP? You gave a hint that it might be a SOAP service, if that is the case then you could generate a client from the WSDL for example with Axis 2.

Comment: you can also check out the metro (http://metro.java.net/) project.

Comment: yes, a SOAP request. there is not a WSDL, so is my only option to use HttpURLConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say you're in control of the other party - or actually you are that party because you just want to do remoting between two JVMs, then use another remoting solution. Depending on your needs, you could use something like protobuf, hessian, or something like Terracotta.
These frameworks are much easier to use and far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a visit to [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org). What you want is not just naked JAX-B, but a JAX-WS+JAX-B service, which will take care of all this for you. In particular, you can use a JAX-WS provider to create a soap endpoint when there is no WSDL.

Comment: I'd recommend against using CXF, since the tool encourages you to create interfaces in Java and then generated WSDL's and XSD's based on those interfaces. The big problem is, when using webservices those WSDL's and XSD's are your contract and when their generated those contract can change to easy - thus any party that has to use your service will have to change their code very often. In practice I've seen numerous times this caused problems.

Comment: CXF is just as happy to do code-first and contract-first services. Blaming the framework for including support for both seems an odd approach.